# How to transform Flutter widget so origin is in the lower left corner?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, transform

Is there a simple way to set up a widget so that the origin is in the lower left corner of the widget, rather than the upper left corner?

Comment: What "origin" are you talking about, and for what widget? If you're talking about coordinates you are using while painting, you can use a canvas transformation that flips the y axis to make the lower left be the 0,0 point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand this well, then yes you can with the `Align` widget
let's say that I have this :

```
Container(
  width: 200,
  height: 200,
  child: Text("text example")
),
```

I can wrap the `Text` widget to show the text in Any plce inside the `Container`

```
  Container(
  width: 200,
  height: 200,
  child: Align(
    alignment: Alignment.bottomRight,
  child: Text("text example"),
  ),
),
```

this will align the text widget in the bottom right of the `Container`.

you can also align with the `Alignment` constructor like this

```
Container(
  width: 200,
  height: 200,
  child: Align(
    alignment: Alignment(-1, 1),
  child: Text("text example"),
  ),
),
```

you can play with values in the range -1<value<1